# How do I JSON serialize a struct with ambiguous embedding in Go?

Tags: json, go

It would seem that having both `Identity` and `Report` embed `CommonProperties` causes omission of all of the common fields in the JSON serialization of the `CompositeObject`.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type CommonProperties struct {
    Type         string    `json:"type,omitempty"`
    ID           string    `json:"id,omitempty"`
    CreatedByRef string    `json:"created_by_ref,omitempty"`
    Created      time.Time `json:"created,omitempty"`
    Modified     time.Time `json:"modified,omitempty"`
    Revoked      bool      `json:"revoked,omitempty"`
    Labels       []string  `json:"labels,omitempty"`
    Confidence   int       `json:"confidence,omitempty"`
    Language     string    `json:"lang,omitempty"`
}

type Identity struct {
    CommonProperties
    Name               string   `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Description        string   `json:"description,omitempty"`
    IdentityClass      string   `json:"identity_class,omitempty"`
    Sectors            []string `json:"sectors,omitempty"`
    ContactInformation string   `json:"contact_information,omitempty"`
}

type Report struct {
    CommonProperties
    Name        string    `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Description string    `json:"description,omitempty"`
    Published   time.Time `json:"published,omitempty"`
    ObjectRefs  []string  `json:"object_refs,omitempty"`
}

type CompositeObject struct {
    InternalID string `json:"uid,omitempty"`
    Pending    bool   `json:"pending"`
    Type       string `json:"type"`

    *Identity
    *Report
}

func main() {
    co := CompositeObject{
        Type:    "report",
        Pending: true,
        Report: &Report{
            Name:        "Spear Phishing Report",
            Description: "...",
            Published:   time.Date(2016, 5, 12, 8, 17, 27, 0, time.UTC),
            ObjectRefs: []string{
                "indicator--26ffb872-1dd9-446e-b6f5-d58527e5b5d2",
                "campaign--83422c77-904c-4dc1-aff5-5c38f3a2c55c",
                "relationship--f82356ae-fe6c-437c-9c24-6b64314ae68a",
            },
            CommonProperties: CommonProperties{
                ID:           "report--84e4d88f-44ea-4bcd-bbf3-b2c1c320bcb3",
                Type:         "report",
                Created:      time.Date(2016, 5, 12, 8, 17, 27, 0, time.UTC),
                CreatedByRef: "identity--a463ffb3-1bd9-4d94-b02d-74e4f1658283",
                Modified:     time.Date(2016, 5, 12, 8, 17, 27, 0, time.UTC),
            },
        },
    }
    json, _ := json.Marshal(&co)
    fmt.Println(string(json))
}
```

Play links:

- https://play.golang.org/p/iVxtYHWVPw
- https://play.golang.org/p/6adrrJ9iac

The second one gets the desired output by commenting out second `CommonProperties` embed.

I don't understand why an embed w/ this type of ambiguity would prevent JSON serialization. Is there a solution that doesn't involve writing a bunch of `MarshalJSON()` functions?

Comment: If there are conflicting fields, there is no way for the marshaller to know what to do with them. You can use struct tags to omit one of the anonymous fields, or to have it encode an anonymous field with a name (as if it weren't anonymous), or you can write your own `MarshalJSON` to use whatever custom logic you need; but in the case of an ambiguity, there is no way without further information from you that the marshaller can know what to do.

Comment: The logic used by the JSON encoder is explained in detail in the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal

Comment: Yeah, it seems like `MarshalJSON` is the right answer then.